# Many to One relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling to implement a Many to One relationship in EF Core.  This is not a one to many, it's a many to one.  I have an object called Order that can be of a specific OrderStatus such as BackOrder, Rush, Fulfilled.  Each of those has many properties associated with it that I need the Order to have access to.  For example each has a different DeliveryCharge, each has a different ManufacturingLine, etc.  It's like an enum with additional properties.

I'm working with a disconnected app so all data gets sent over the wire as JSON.

Setting this up with a standard FK works when querying the data and viewing on the front end.  However when I save EF thinks the OrderStatus is a new entity so it tries to insert, resulting in a key conflict.

I've gotten things to work with a "fixup" process during the save that requeries the OrderStatus just before Order save and replaces the "new" OrderStatus object with an identical one from the DB.

Is there a way to declare a Many to One relationship in EF core

This is what the relationship looks like.
[image]

Comment: Many-to-One *is* a One-to-Many viewed from the other side. A `Product` object with a `Category` property has a Many-to-One relation with `Category`. Post your code instead of describing it. `EF thinks the OrderStatus is a new entity so it tries to insert, resulting in a key conflict.` that's a *different* question which has to do with change tracking and the code you use to save, not relations.

Comment: no, it's not.  in one to many the navigation starts from the parent (the one) and goes to the children (the many), like orders and line items.  I want to go the other direction. In EF the parent does not have a pointer to its children, the children each have a pointer to it's parent.

Comment: Whether INSERT or UPDATE is used depends on change tracking, and how detached objects are attached to DbContext, not relations. If an object attached with `Attach` has an empty ID (or primary key property), EF Core will assume it's new and INSERT it. If that object is explicitly attached in a specific state with `Add` or `Update`, EF Core will use INSERT or UPDATE respectively.

Comment: I don't want *either* insert or update.  No data has changed in the OrderStatus code.  I want to map many Orders to the same OrderStatus but not create a new OrderStatus

Comment: *In EF the parent does not have a pointer to its children, the children each have a pointer to it's parent* - that's not a one/many relationship, it's a one/one. Each one child has one parent

Comment: You said the problem is that `when I save EF thinks the OrderStatus is a new entity so it tries to insert, resulting in a key conflict.`. Post your code. EF deals with entities, not tables. Database relations have no direction - in fact, Foreign Keys are *constraints* not relations. The images you posted are more confusing than the description. EF Core would have no problem with an `OrderStatus` property pointing to an existing `OrderStatus` value, provided that `OrderStatus` had a non-default ID

Comment: @BradIrby Then map them with code (since the serializer does not do that for you as I understand). EF Core won't do that automatically for you as well. Replace the references with `db.Find(refId)` before add/update the dependent entity.

Comment: *However when I save EF thinks the OrderStatus is a new entity so it tries to insert, resulting in a key conflict* - don't make a new entity for the parent, just set the parentid on the new child to the known parent id. If you don't have a OrderStatusId int on the child, provide one, or download the existing known OrderStatus parent entity first

Comment: If you use `DbContext.Add(order)`, EF Core will attach any child objects as *new*, and try to insert them as well. From [the Add docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-6.0)  `Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked, in the Added state such that they will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges() is called.` Is that what happened here?

Comment: @CaiusJard They are explaining one-to-many relationship with only reference navigation property at dependent (mixing navigations with relations and relation ends). And have a typical problem with JSON creating different instances with the same Id. Or calling `Add` with disconnected entity having untracked references.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's what I'm doing now, but I was hoping for a cleaner way.  It looks like I'll have to continue with the fixup code.

Comment: You don't have to continue with the fixup code, you just have to remove the bump you've placed in the rug, that you're now tripping over. Some part of the process is introducing a new entity *that is not new* - do that part differently

Comment: Maybe it is better to use [ChangeTracker.TrackGraph()](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-trackgraph-ef-core.aspx)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv `TrackGraph` does not help with "there is already tracked entity reference with the same key blah-blah".

Comment: @IvanStoev, well good to know. I thought they have introduced `TrackGraph` exactly for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This might be coming about because you're deserializing some JSON directly to a DB-level entity; the serializer is reconstructing an entity graph for you and you're handing that graph to EF and saying "save this". Because the serializer has created a new OrderStatus with existing properties, and EF thinks it's new it will try to save it. This problem is usually avoided by having a different set of models for the front end, shuttled via JSON between browser and webserver, than are used for the back end, shuttled between web server and DB by EF. The mapping process in the web server in the middle of that chain provides an opportunity for makign sure the DB entity graph is somethign EF can handle.

It doesn't mean you can't deser and save a DB entity graph, though we do try to avoid sending DB ents to the front end, but if you *are* going to save a deser'd DB entity graph it is incumbent upon some part of the process that *knows whether an entity is new or not* to *not send* a complete new entity to EF, if it is existing..

It would be simplest to make your entities like:

```
public class OrderStatus{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}

  public int DeliveryCharge....
}

public class Order{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int OrderStatusId {get;set;}
  public OrderStatus OrderStatus {get;set;}

  public blah LotsOf....
}
```

Then if you know an order status id exists and want to add an order that uses that existing id:

```
context.Orders.Add(new Order { OrderStatusId = 2, Other = blah });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or with the "the front-end built it and the webserver just deser'd it" approach of sending JSON:

```
{
  OrderStatusId: 2,
  Other: ...
}
```

And not:

```
{
  OrderStatus: { Id: 2, DeliveryCharge: 5, ..}
  Other: ...
}
```

Doing the former might be as simple as tweaking your javascript so it just puts an ID in the object sent for seralization, rather than putting the whole object; when the user chooses "$5 express delivery" from the combo, put `OrderStatusId:2` in the request entity, not `OrderStaus:{ Id: 2, Delivery: 5, ..}`

In the latter form the serializer will construct another entity for you, leaving you with the problem of post processing it out (easy enough, just a bit wasteful):

```
foreach(var o in deserializeddOrders){
  o.OrderStatusId = o.OrderStatus.Id;
  o.OrderStatus = null;
}
```

---

If you aren't willing to provide an OrderStatusId and have a known OrderStatus in memory already (you downloaded it for some reason) you can:

```
context.Orders.Add(new Order { OrderStatus = <existing entity>, Other = blah });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or postprocessing deser'd:

```
foreach(var o in deserializedOrders){
  o.OrderStatus = <existing ent>;
}
```

If you do not have a known entity it;s simplest to download the existing entity using whatever other retrieval approach you would like to take, and provide it as the matching entity:

```
context.Orders.Add(new Order { OrderStatus = context.OrderStatuses.Find(2), Other = blah });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or as a postprocess:

```
foreach(var o in deserializedOrders){
  o.OrderStatus = context.OrderStatus.Find(o.OrderStatus.Id); //find will only download from db once; further retrievals use a cached item
}
```

But *don't* make a new status entity with an existing ID, because EF will try to insert it:

```
context.Orders.Add(new Order { OrderStatus = new () { Id = 2 }, Other = blah });
context.SaveChanges();
```

There are other things you can do to solve this, such as fiddling with the change tracker to make EF think a new entity is existing but I'm not a fan.. If all you have is an ID, popping it into a paired ...Id property on the child is the intended solution, so make sure that's what happens